# Convergence to Riemann-Stieltjes integral of sequence of Riemann-Stieltjes-like sums with changing integrand and integrator

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

I am considering the limiting behavior of a sequence of Riemann-Stieltjes (RS) (or at least RS-like) sums in the sense of their convergence to a Riemann-Stieltjes integral. The general term has the form

\begin{equation}
  \sum_{n=0}^N \, f_N(t_n^{(N)}) \, [F_N(x_n^{(N)}) - F_N(x_{n-1}^{(N)})] \,,  
\end{equation}

where $x_{-1}^{(N)} := 0$ for every value of $N$, every partition $\{ x_n^{(N)} \}_{n=-1}^N$ is of the unit real interval $[0,1]$ with $x_N^{(N)} = 1$, the argument $t_n^{(N)}$ belongs to the subinterval $[x_{n-1}^{(N)}, x_n^{(N)}]$ of $[0,1]$ (actually, in my more specific setting it is $t_n^{(N)} = x_n^{(N)}$), and the partition for $N+1$ is a refinement of that for $N$. I think everything is as usual for an RS sum except for the particularity that there is no fixed function having the role of integrator, but rather a sequence $(F_N)_N$ thereof, and similarly for the integrand, which is defined in terms of the sequence $(f_N)_N$.

As for the functions, they are all real of a single real variable. Those in the sequence $(f_N)_N$ are continuous and bounded in $[0,1]$, and the sequence converges to a continuous function f bounded in the same interval. In turn, those in $(F_N)_N$ are monotonically increasing step functions bounded in $[0,1]$ and the sequence is uniformly convergent to a function F that is a cumulative distribution function. My overall objective is to prove that the sequence of sums converges to the RS integral $\int_0^1 \, f(x) \, \mathrm{d}F(x)$.

Any hints on how to proceed will be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Start by writing

$$\tag{*}\left| \sum_{n=0}^N \, f_N(t_n^{(N)}) \, [F_N(x_n^{(N)}) - F_N(x_{n-1}^{(N)})]- \int_0^1 f \, dF \right| \\ \leqslant \left| \sum_{n=0}^N \, f_N(t_n^{(N)}) \, [F_N(x_n^{(N)}) - F_N(x_{n-1}^{(N)})]-  \sum_{n=0}^N \, f(t_n^{(N)}) \, [F_N(x_n^{(N)}) - F_N(x_{n-1}^{(N)})] \right| \\ + \left| \sum_{n=0}^N \, f(t_n^{(N)}) \, [F_N(x_n^{(N)}) - F_N(x_{n-1}^{(N)})]-  \sum_{n=0}^N \, f(t_n^{(N)}) \, [F(x_n^{(N)}) - F(x_{n-1}^{(N)})] \right| \\+ \left| \sum_{n=0}^N \, f(t_n^{(N)}) \, [F(x_n^{(N)}) - F(x_{n-1}^{(N)})]- \int_0^1 f \, dF \right|,$$

and try to estimate each term as $N \to \infty.$

Uniform convergence of both $f_N \to f$ and $F_N \to F$ would be helpful.

For the first term on the RHS of (*) , with uniform convergence, we have  for sufficiently large $N$ and all $x \in [0,1]$,

$$|f_N(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon, \,\,\, F_N(1) < F(1) + \epsilon, \,\,\, F_N(0) > F(0) - \epsilon$$

Hence,

$$ \left| \sum_{n=0}^N \, f_N(t_n^{(N)}) \, [F_N(x_n^{(N)}) - F_N(x_{n-1}^{(N)})]-  \sum_{n=0}^N \, f(t_n^{(N)}) \, [F_N(x_n^{(N)}) - F_N(x_{n-1}^{(N)})] \right|\\ \leqslant  \sum_{n=0}^N \, |f_N(t_n^{(N)})- f(t_n^{(N)}) | \, [F_N(x_n^{(N)}) - F_N(x_{n-1}^{(N)})] \\ \leqslant \epsilon \sum_{n=0}^N \,  \, [F_N(x_n^{(N)}) - F_N(x_{n-1}^{(N)})]  \\ = \epsilon[F_N(1) - F_N(0)] \\ \leqslant \epsilon[F(1) - F(0) + 2\epsilon$$

The convergence of the last term on the RHS of (*) is not always guaranteed when $f$ is R-S integrable with respect to $F$ except under strong conditions. It seems you have that part -- both because the partitions in the sequence are refinements and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I guess that you first line in the RHS is a typo to be removed, though. I'll try as you suggest and see how far I can go.

Comment: @Marco:  Where is the typo?

Comment: The entire first line.

Comment: The first line is $|S(P_N,f_N,F_N) - \int_0^1 f \, dF|$ with $S(...)$ shorthand for the sum.  This is the very thing you want to show converges to $0$.

Comment: I mean the first displayed line in the RHS of the inequality.

Comment: I am writing $|S(P_N,f_N,F_N)-\int fdF| \leqslant |S(P_N,f_N,F_N) -S(P_N,f,F_N)| + | S(P_N,f,F_N) - S(P,f,F)| + |S(P_N,f,F)- \int fdF|$.

Comment: ... and the first term on the RHS is easy to estimate if $f_N \to f$ uniformly.

Comment: Right. I had missed the "unindexed" $f$. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem.  I just showed how the first term on the RHS is small for large $N$ when we have uniform convergence.  The third term converges as I said under your hypotheses.  All you have to do is handle the second term which should be easy because $f$ is bounded and $F_N \to F$ uniformly.

Comment: @Marcos.  Nice question -- I think it will work out.

Comment: Thanks so much. I also think your approach will work out. I'll be back as soon as I have worked out the details.

Comment: You're welcome.  I could do it all - but it is much better for you to complete it.

Comment: Rightly so. I appreciate.